# Getting SQL queries behind objects in Business Objects BI4 with the API

Tags: business-objects

I'm currently using the BO BI4 REST API to retrieve metadata from a universe but all I was able to do was to get the list of the objects with their ID, path and type.
I would like to know if it is possible to get the SQL called when I use these objects with the API.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want to get the generated SQL for the whole query, or just the single SELECT clause for a specific object?

Comment: I would like to have the SELECT clause for every object of my universe

Answer (score 0):

It's not as easy as it should be.

The WebI REST API doesn't expose objects' SQL.

You can get summary information about universes, including their objects but **not** SQL, by using the Semantic Layer REST API.

To get all of universe objects' info, including SQL, you will need to use another SDK.  For unx universes, use the [Semantic Layer SDK](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4359a0ef221e4a1098bae432bdd982c1/4.2.4/en-US).  For unv universes, the only option is the mostly-undocumented Designer COM SDK.